# How to store filtered data from JSON and display in table (EmberJS)

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

I am trying to display a table of records on page load in EmberJS. The data comes from an ajax call, which gives a very large JSON response. Here is an overview of the process (how it should work):
**Page Loads -> Ajax call ( in controller) -> Response  -> Store Data somewhere (filtered) -> Display in Table**

So far I have been successful in getting a JSON response, but the data is huge and contains multiple fields and nested fields. I only need to store certain data from the response such as **name**, **email** etc.

Here is the code for my controller which is run when the page loads:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Controller.extend({
ajax: Ember.inject.service(),
init:function(){
  const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token')
  this.get('ajax').request('http://127.0.0.1/SugarPro-Full-8.0.0/rest/v10/Leads',{
    method: 'GET',
    headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'oauth-token': `${token}`
    },
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      sessionStorage.setItem("data", response);
    },
    error: function(){
      window.alert("Please Login!");
      window.location.assign("/login-page");

    },
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}
});
```

**NOTE:** I'm storing the response in `sessionStorage` because I do not know where to go from here, so that may be ignored if required.

**PS:** I did see a few examples that suggested to put everything in the router, but that was when they assumed the response was a *subset* of the model, whereas in my case it's probably the other way around.

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should move it to the route! Also can you show how your data is structured? maybe a anonymized and reduced example?

Comment: Could you please explain how i would move this to route? any changes to be required? And if so how would that benefit the program overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) certain properties to another filtered array like this and save mapped data to your `sessionStorage`:

```
success: function(response){
  mappedresponse = response.map(item =>{
    return {"name": item.name, "email": item.email};
  });
  console.log(mappedresponse);
  sessionStorage.setItem("data", mappedresponse);
},
```